# Weird console output in TortoiseHG

Tags: tortoisehg

Having using TortoiseHG for 3+ years, I've never seen this in the console before, but within the last few days, I've seen this same pattern outputted to the console a couple of times while updating or pushing (not sure which). Anyone know what's going on?

[image]

Comment: Is it open repo? Can you try to repeat operation (which?) in plain console?

Comment: It looks very much like the Atlassian logo...

Comment: It appears someone contributed to the code, and decided to add their signature for everyone to appreciate. Got to love open source! All we need is some other volunteer coder to get into the code, find where this was inserted, and remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is an Atlassian signature. Are you pushing to [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org) or a hosted instance of [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash) by any chance?

[image: Atlassian logo]

It's not indicative of a problem with your TortoiseHG instance. Just disregard it. Or if it really bothers you, [complain to Atlassian](https://support.atlassian.com) directly.

Comment: I'm pushing to bitbucket. Thanks for the reply. Glad to hear there's no issue with my instance of tortoiseHG.